# Why different paddings on mobile and desktop Flutter platforms

Tags: flutter, layout, padding

Why is the default padding value different on desktop and mobile platforms, and how to get the same layout on Android [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNvOH.png) as on Linux [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn2Lc.png)? I want to remove the padding on Android.

I noticed this problem with the Row, Column, Wrap widgets.
For example on Android there is a spacing but not on Linux.
Please check the following example.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('A1')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('A2')),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('B1')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('B2')),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

[image: Android]

[image: Linux]

Comment: tried to change this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/visualDensity.html?

Comment: @pskink I tried, it has no effect.

Comment: @pskink Just try yourself. I want to remove the padding on Android just like on Linux. It does not work, it only changes the buttons' size.

Comment: i am on Linux desktop so cannot check on android, `materialTapTargetSize` seems to introduce the padding, check it on android - it seems that it defaults to `MaterialTypeTarvetSize.padded` on android platform

Comment: @pskink OK I found it, thanks! I've set the elevatedButtonTheme in ThemeData. If you create an answer I'll accept it.